# Is that possible to do it with just CSS?

Tags: css

I've a menu that is an unordered list.

What I want to do is that when the width of the screen/browser is less than certain pixels, the menu becomes options in form, is that possible to achieve this by using just CSS, but not PHP, JS, nor other language(s)?

Right now I can only think of CSS' media queries, but it can only styles the menu but can't change it from a list to form's options, any other suggestions?

Thanks a lot,

Kenny

Comment: Anything is possible if you believe! On a serious note, 'is x possible [with y]' questions are a bit off-topic unless you've tried something and have a specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to show one menu when you're over expected screen width and the other one when user screen is less or equal to needed width?

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu-mobile">
     <form>
          <input type="radio" name="menu" value="home">
          <input type="radio" name="menu" value="about">
     </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    display: block;
} 

#menu-mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
     #menu { display: none; }
     #menu-mobile { display: block; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul></ul>
```

and

```
<form>
    <select></select>
</form>
```

are completely different thing.

You can only create the menu in these 2 formats and use css media queries to decide which one to display in certain width